# How to send calling class name to logger class in Python >

Tags: python

I am new to Python and trying to implement logger in my code.
I have created a python file: setup_logger.py

```
import logging

CLASS_NAME = ''

# Create and configure logger
LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(filename='/Users/bobby/Desktop/lumberjack.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format=LOG_FORMAT)
logger = logging.getLogger()
```

I am using this logger configuration in another python file: GetLogger.py as below

```
from LoggerLevels.setup_logger import logger

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.error('This is a basic log error message')
    logger.info('This is a warning message')
```

The log is being printed in the file as:

```
2020-06-17 14:54:47,161 - root - ERROR - This is a basic log error message
2020-06-17 14:54:47,161 - root - INFO - This is a warning message
```

But I see the class name is printed as `root`. I understand that it is coming due to the setting in `setup_logger.py` file. 
Is there anyway I can send the current class name that is logging messages into my file ?
For ex: 
I am using the logger object from `GetLogger.py` file. Is there anyway I can log the message as

```
2020-06-17 14:54:47,161 - GetLogger - ERROR - This is a basic log error message
2020-06-17 14:54:47,161 - GetLogger - INFO - This is a warning message
```

Could anyone let me know how can I achieve that ?

Comment: here is a list of other attributes if you want https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```py
LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s - %(module)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
```

If that doesn't work for you, you can try `%(filename)s` or create a custom class with [setLoggerClass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.setLoggerClass) method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a advice for you to take it as a reference.

```
logger_format = '%(asctime)s [%(className)s] %(funcName)s | %(message)s (%(name)s)'
extra_dict = {'className': 'NameOfClass'}
logger = logging.getLogger('logger_name')

def callLogger():
    logger.debug('log message', extra=extra_dict)

callLogger()
```

And result would be like:

> 2021-02-21 17:08:34,066 [NameOfClass] callLogger | log message (logger_name)

When we use the same logger in different class, this way is also work.

If you use different logger in each class, you have easier way like:

```
# put the (%(name)s) to position of name of class
logger_format = '%(asctime)s [%(name)s] %(funcName)s | %(message)s'

# name the logger name as class name
logger = logging.getLogger('NameOfClass')

def callLogger():
    logger.debug('log message')

callLogger()
```

And result would be like:

> 2021-02-21 17:08:34,066 [NameOfClass] callLogger | log message

Refer to [Python official document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug)